# Assign object to some value inside Task of object by maintaining async

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, task, task-parallel-library

I don't have much expertise in TPL.

Consider the following scenario:

I have the following classes:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have the following piece of code

```
Task<Contact> contactDetails = r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Contact>();
Task<Company> companyDetails = r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Company>();
```

Now, What I want to is to populate Company property by the companyDetails result. something like that (please check below)

```
contactDetails.Company = companyDetails
```

I want to do this without calling await function to maintain async.

Can anybody, please help me to do this?

Comment: `companyDetails` is of type `Task<Company>` so you cannot just assign it to variable of type `Company`. It is more like a promise that you will have result once it is finished. You can call `Task<T>.Result` to retrieve result, however be aware that calling thread will block until task is finished which is something you want to avoid when using TPL...

Comment: Yes, we can do this way to get the result and assign it. But that's not what I'm looking for. I want to do it without block thread until I use await.

Comment: @Saadi Could you please clarify your reason for not wanting to use `await`?

Comment: @pere57, Already highlighted on my above comment that await block thread,

Comment: Downvoters - please tell me what is wrong in this question?

Comment: The Task<T> is not the actual object. Like said above it is a promise to get the object. So when you have Task<T> you cannot assign properties to the object T. The Task<T> might  not return the object T. It might throw an exception.

Comment: So you have to await the Task and get the result before working with the object. Though you can put this in another Task and then it will only be excuted when awaiting the Task, which is what I showed.

Comment: @Saadi `await` doesn't block the thread. It's an asynchronous wait, not a blocking wait. `await` is exactly the tool you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Say you create an async method like below:

```
public async Task<Contact> GetContact()
{
    R r = new R();

    Contact contactDetails = await r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Contact>();
    Company companyDetails = await r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Company>();

    contactDetails.Company = companyDetails;

    Console.WriteLine("3");
    return contactDetails;
}
```

This will not execute until you await this GetContact. So, for example if we call it using the below code:

```
Console.WriteLine("1");
Task<Contact> getContactTask = GetContact();
Console.WriteLine("2");
Contact contact = await getContactTask; // the code is now executed
Console.WriteLine("4");
```

The console would show:

```
1
2
3
4
```

According to your comment, I think this is what you want. Get contact and get company will not execute until you call await on the GetContact method.

Also if you want to execute both get contact and get company parallel you could use the following:

```
public async Task<Contact> GetCompanyParallel()
{
    R r = new R();

    Task<Contact> contactDetailsTask = r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Contact>();
    Task<Company> companyDetailsTask = r.FirstOrDefaultAsync<Company>();

    await Task.WhenAll(contactDetailsTask, companyDetailsTask);

    Contact contactDetails = await contactDetailsTask;
    contactDetails.Company = await companyDetailsTask;

    return contactDetails;
}
```